# Why can we assume an algorithm can be represented as a bit string?

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, computability, computation-models

I am starting read a book about Computational Complexity and Turing Machines. Here is quote:

> An algorithm (i.e., a machine) can be represented as a bit string once
>   we decide on some canonical encoding.

This assertion is provided as a simple fact, but I can't understand it.

For example, if I have an algorithm which takes $x$ as input and computes $(x+1)^2$ or:

```
int function (int x){
   x = x + 1; 
   return x**2; 
}
```

How that can this be represented as string using alphabet $\{0, 1\}^*$?

Comment: You do not know the absolute minimum required knowledge to understand how text is encoded.  Today is a great day to learn! https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: I think OP might be coming at this from a different point of view based on an ambiguity in the quoted text. I guess OP means 'how can the whole machine and algorithm be built as a bit string,' not the input to the Turing machine itself. The quoted text implies that the whole algorithm can be self executed, but a utf encoded bit of c language says nothing about how a machine would actually act on that string.

Comment: ...I think everyone here is misunderstanding the source and taking the joke too far, at the expense of Roma's inexperience.  Most of these comments and answers are talking about encoding the text for arbitrary transmission, while the quote is talking about encoding the algorithm for consumption by a turing machine.  The (currently) accepted answer at least touches on it in the second sentence.

Comment: @Izkata I’m not sure if you’re aware that, due to universality, these two statements are equivalent.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "algorithm". Mathematicians happily call things "algorithm" that *can't* be encoded as a finite bit string.

Comment: The funny thing is that in order for me to be able to read your coded algorithm it *necessarily* had to be turned into a sequence of bits as soon as you typed it. It never was represented differently -- all the way from your keyboard to my monitor. It had a non-binary representation only in our minds; and on the physiological level, when you look at synapses, even that is debatable.

Comment: In your example, assume that the text of the function is a UTF-8 encoded string, and each 8 bit unit of a UTF-8 string is trivially encoded as eight 0/1 strings.

Comment: What you need is an *encoding*. For instance a (compiled) program is a binary that contains a sequence of zeros and ones. The processor each time fetches a number a "word" and interprets this and processes it, for example 80x86 ASM.

Comment: If this is about wether it's possible to create an Esoteric Programming Language which only uses 2 characters to code? Have a look at [Unreadable](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable). Basically, even with 2 letters you can create multiple "words" that represent instructions.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The most naive and simple answer to your question is that the code provided (and compiled machine code) are in-fact represented as syntactic strings of {0,1}*. Additionally, since you are talking about turing machines, the programs they run are a linear list of operations/instructions, there is no reason these cannot be represented as bits/bytes.

Comment: How exactly do you represent Turing machine as a list of instructions? The usual definition is [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition).

Comment: @svick As mentioned in my answer below, you use a universal TM, which takes the description of a TM as input (encoded in a suitable fashion)

Comment: @svick A programming language with simple instructions to move a pointer accross a tape?  I believe an example of such could be the esoteric programming language [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). [Example code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55506/42827)

Comment: @LukStorms I don't think you can call that a "Turing machine" anymore.

Answer (score 52):

You already have a representation of that function as text.  Convert each character to a one-byte value using the ASCII encoding.  Then the result is a sequence of bytes, i.e., a sequence of bits, i.e., a string over the alphabet $\{0,1\}^*$. That's one example encoding.

Comment: Exactly. And as I said above, it happened while Roma wrote it. Even the glyphs I see on my monitor are b&w pixels, i.e. binary information, sent over a binary data connection from a binary memory connected to a binary network through binary controllers. Is it *possible* to represent every algorithm as a bit string? More than that: it's *unavoidable* unless you limit yourself to analog media and face-to-face communication.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Using analog media or face-to-face does not necessarily imply that there is no embedded discrete encoding. Using a natural language is not far away from using a discrete encoding, isn't it?

Answer (score 34):

I can't resist...

```
⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡀⣰⡉⡀⠀⡀⡀⣀⠀⢀⣀⢀⣄⡀⡂⢀⣀⡀⢀⢀⡀⠀⡰⣀⠀⣀⠀⡂⡀⣀⢀⣄⡰⡀⢠⠂
⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⢸⠀⡇⢀⡇⡏⠀⡇⣏⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⣏⠀⣹⢸⠁⢸⠀⡇⢈⠷⡁⠀⡇⡏⠀⡇⡇⠀⡇⢼⠀
⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠁⠈⠀⠈⠁⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠉⠀⠈⠁⠁⠈⠉⠁⠈⠀⠈⠀⠱⠉⠀⠉⠀⠁⠁⠀⠁⠈⠱⠁⠘⠄
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⣀⣀⣀⠀⢤⡀⡤⠀⠀⢰⠀⠀⢹⠠⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠒⠒⠒⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠉⢹⠉⠁⢸⢀⠀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⠀
⠀⠀⠀⣄⢄⠤⢄⢴⠤⢠⠀⢠⢠⡠⢠⡠⢄⠀⢤⡀⡤⢺⡖⠐⣷⠂⠊⢉⡆
⠀⠀⠀⡇⠸⣍⣉⠸⣀⠸⣀⢼⢸⠀⢸⠀⢸⠀⣠⠛⣄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣴⣋⡀
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

⢱⠀
⢸⠁
⠊
```

(The dots above represent ones, the blanks zeroes).

Comment: Amusing (+1) but it serves to underscore the essentially arbitrary nature of the encoding.

Comment: Have fun writing the compiler for this :)

Comment: Reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers

Comment: @Barmar Sounds like a challenge for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: Which site did you use to draw it?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich [here's the function](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/pcf-font/blob/e61cf62cf9770ca1749d1b7afbc3596b41d09577/src/Graphics/Text/PCF.hs#L338) that does the rendering to Braille characters. [Here's a simple wrapper](https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/f09cecbdb39c39fc19fc8f560ad8939d) that allows calling it from the command-line.

Comment: The most fun thing is that you wrote `x int` instead of `int x`

Answer (score 13):

Your computer stores everything as sequences of `0` and `1`, including the question you typed to ask how it does it. For instance, each letter and symbol is represented by 8-bits (I am talking about how things used to be, nowadays it's 16-bits, and more complicated). You can see [them here](https://www.asciitable.com). Well, they are not showing the bits, but rather the hexadecimal and octal codes. Do you know how to convert a number to its digital representation?

Comment: It's 16 bytes only on Windows and in some libraries like Qt or ICU, which use UTF-16. And not even all letters take a single code unit in general, even in UTF-32, so they may be longer. So I think it's better to stick to ASCII in this discussion, bringing Unicode here will lead to quite a complication.

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental hypothesis behind this concept is the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis).  It may be hard to see that any algorithm can be represented as a string of bits, because the term "algorithm" may be thought of in very informal terms.  In the Church-Turing thesis, they use a very rigorously defined concept of what an algorithm is (and even then there have been a few questions about words).  However, their terminology has gotten so much sway that it is sometimes argued that these definitions for words like "algorithm" are so effective that we simply accept them as *the* definition.

Church-Turing states that every algorithm can be implemented as a computation on a Turing Machine.  Given that the description of a Turing Machine is a finite set of values, it is trivial to see how to map this description into a sequence of numbers, and then into a sequence of 0's and 1s.

As the other answers have mentioned, it's trivial to represent your example algorithm by using ASCII encoding or other encodings.

I think the reason why your book gives this statement as a *fact* stems from the fact that many simply use the Church-Turing thesis as the basis for their definition of an algorithm.  If you use such a definition, it is as obvious of a fact as is "5 is a number" because you basically defined it as such.

Comment: The Church-Turing thesis is *not* a theorem and it doesn't involve any definition for the concept of algorithm, which is an informal one. I also don't see the need to invoke the Church-Turing thesis for this. The "deep" reason why some objects can be represented as finite strings and some cannot is that some sets are countable and some aren't.

Comment: I'm seeing "an algorithm can be encoded as a string if we specify an injection between the components of the machine specification and the set of strings in a language."  OP does this in his example, taking the machine represented by "\$(x+1)^2\$" and re-representing it as a string in the language of well-formed C (or BCPL, C++, et al.) functions.

Comment: @EricTowers Which does require the Church-Turing thesis.  Otherwise one cannot be certain that there exists a machine specification of an algorithm for all algorithms.

Comment: @EricTowers What definitions are you thinking of?  I do agree that it is possible that the connection is trivial, if you choose to define algorithm in a way which makes it trivial.  For example, if the concept of an algorithm has, as one of its requirements, "an algorithm can be written down," then we're set!  But what if my algorithm requires an uncountably infinite number of symbols to express?  Is there any logic which ensures that such a construct does not qualify as an "algorithm?"

Comment: Random book from my computability shelf, Sommerhalder and Westrhenen, The Theory of Computability, 1988, section 2.2: "An algorithm is a finite description specifying a computation over a certain data type for any given input."  Computation is defined over a many-sorted algebra of finite cartesian products of naturals, booleans, alphabets, strings over these alphabets.  The finite collection of allowed operations are enumerated.  Gurari 1989, specifies a finite programming language and a finite list of primitive types.

Comment: I assert that an "algorithm [that] requires an uncountably infinite number of symbols to express" cannot be expressed.  Such an expression must use uncountably many symbols, otherwise, it can be expressed in a smaller sublanguage.  Further, any (non-silly) expression over an infinite alphabet has an infinite amount of entropy in almost all of its symbols, so defies expression (i.e., cannot actually communicate to a recipient).  All finitary logics refuse to operate on such infinite strings and I am not aware of an infinitary logic that will permit working on uncountable strings.

Comment: @EricTowers [Point 2 here looks like OP's source](https://books.google.com/books?id=8Wjqvsoo48MC&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75626/discussion-on-answer-by-cort-ammon-why-can-we-assume-an-algorithm-can-be-represe).

Answer (score 4):

This statement is based on the existence of [universal TMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine). These are basically programmable TMs that can simulate any other TM with at most poly overhead. Therefore, your program is simply part of the input encoded as zeros and ones.

Comment: @Discretelizard, I don't follow you.  Any algorithm is expressible as an input to a universal TM.  Languages can be computable or uncomputable; I'm not familiar with any standard notion of computability for algorithms, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.  What would it mean to have an uncomputable algorithm?  Perhaps you're thinking of algorithms that don't necessarily terminate?  But a universal TM can still run such algorithms.

Comment: @Discretelizard I don't follow you, either. Being runnable on a Turing machine is essentially the _definition_ of an algorithm. I suppose you could talk about an "algorithm" for, say, a Turing machine with an oracle for the halting problem but, normally, "algorithm" means "thing you can do on a Turing machine."

Comment: @DavidRicherby True, the actual definition of algorithm is more strict, I suppose. But this question regards is about why we impose a much more lenient restriction and saying that there is an even stronger restriction isn't very instructive, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Well, let's talk about algorithms that cannot be represented as a finite bit-string for any kind of encoding.

Let me type out such an algorithm for you... Ah, but if I do that, I can represent that algorithm with the encoding of my typed text.

How about representing my algorithm using some 'analog means', say by the position of a few coins on my desk. Although the position of those coins can be modeled by some real numbers (which could in *some* encodings be impossible to finitely represent), this entire description can again be considered an representation of my algorithm and can be encoded to a bit-string again!

I hope that these examples make it clear that if some algorithm cannot be represented by a finite bit-string we have no means of describing this algorithm at all!

So, why would we consider the existence of something we cannot speak of? Perhaps interesting for philosophy, but not for science. Hence, we define the notion of *algorithm* such that it can be represented by a bit-string, as then we at least know that we are able to talk about all algorithms.

---

Although the above answer the question asked, I think the confusion about the example given is mostly due to the fact that a representation only needs to uniquely represent some algorithm. The manner of representation doesn't need to involve the *actual computations* invoked by the algorithm! This is very useful, as it means we can also represent *uncomputable* algorithms!

Comment: " if some algorithm cannot be represented by a finite bit-string we have no means of describing this algorithm at all! " -- That's not quite true. One might say: "For every real number $r$, consider algorithm $A_r$ as ...". Then most of those algorithms can't be written down but, somehow, we still have expressed them all.

Comment: $A_r$ is clearly a representation of that algorithm and for all algorithm you wish to represent, simple pick a symbol to represent a value from $\mathbb{R}$. So, the algorithm can be represented. Note that this is only a one-way implication, the other way around need not hold.

Comment: Yes! Lovely! Wittgenstein! ["Wovon man nicht sprechen kann, darüber muss man schweigen."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus#Proposition_7)

Comment: @Discretelizard You'll run out of symbols for $r$ quickly.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, and? It should be no surprise that writing down an uncountable number of algorithms isn't possible. And again, you claim that you "express" some algorithms that cannot be written down. I don't understand what you mean by "express", but it seems to at least imply representation. As my claim starts with the assumption that an algorithm is _not_ being represented, I fail to see how this contradicts my claim.

Comment: We're able to "express" a well-defined set of algorithms (assuming our notion of "algorithm" includes such things), only some of which can be finitely represented individually, and fewer again can actually be implemented by TM-equivalent models. (Of course, I'm "cheating". If we can't "cheat", we end up with at best TM-equivalent notions, for which the answer is boring. As far as we know.) I'm really just nitpicking your claim that we can only express things that can be finitely represented.

Comment: @Raphael I still don't understand why you think "that we can only express things that can be finitely represented" is false. I mean, according to my definitions, such an expression _is_ a finite representation. Perhaps our definitions differ. Perhaps we should continue this in [chat] (or some other chat)?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see this is through information theory.  All encodings of meaningful/useful information/questions can be made into binary 'sequences'.

Much of the field goes to the question, "what is the way to ask the least average number of questions to communicate a meaningful piece of information?"  In practice, this is the same as "what is the optimal approach to asking the least number of yes/no questions to understand what was communicated or said?"